# How to make a diagonal line and fill the top and bottom with color?

Tags: html, svg

I'm trying to make a 2 plot graph with line using SVG, not sure if it's the best way to do it

http://www.w3schools.com/svg/tryit.asp?filename=trysvg_line

Comment: Is the question the title or the content as they seem to be two different things.

Comment: Question is the title

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need a couple of triangles which you can do with paths. M is a move and L is a line to. Filling the paths gives triangles.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<svg height="210" width="500">
  <path d="M0,0 L200,200,0,200" fill="black"/>
  <path d="M0,0 L200,200,200,0" fill="red"/>
  Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
</svg>

</body>
</html>
```